# Keras model.load_weights() cannot recognize capital letters

Tags: model, keras

loading your model from json and the weights from h5,

using

```
    from keras.models import model_from_json
    ...

    model.load_weights(modelweights+'.h5')
```

does result in an error as the file cannot be found.loading_weights() apparently changes all capital letters to small ones. Is there a trick or is that just a bug? I am not to keen on changing quite a handful of filenames.

Thanks for the help.

edit: 
 Lodaing the model like this

```
   def ModelLaden(destination,modelname,modelweights):
          json_file = open(destination+modelname+'.json', 'r')
          loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
          json_file.close()
          loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
          loaded_model.load_weights(modelweights+'.h5')
          return loaded_model 

   Bimodel=ModelLaden(destination,modelname,modelweights)
```

thereby the file name is e.g. :

```
modelweights='18_AS_QS_MMCcECG_ResWGRUmodel_weigths'
```

the destination is a windows path to the data e.g.

```
destination=('C:/Users/3101253/Documents/PhD/Article_(MMC)/Results/')
```

the error message is:

> OSError: Unable to open file (Unable to open file: name =
>   '18_as_qs_mmccecg_reswgrumodel_weigths.h5', errno = 2, error message =
>   'no such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)

if you compare the filename you can see the problem

> 18_as_qs_mmccecg_reswgrumodel_weigths # changed
>   18_AS_QS_MMCcECG_ResWGRUmodel_weigths # original

**-----------------------------------------------------------------**

**SOLVED**

I forgot to give the full path to the h5 stored files as I did for the json files. Instead of `loaded_model.load_weights(modelweights+'.h5')`
correct would be `loaded_model.load_weights(destination+modelweights+'.h5')`
Stupid error. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Please include additional information, I don't really believe the problem is upper/lower case.

Comment: HI Matias, I added a bit more information, I hope this is sufficient. I actually had a similar problem before where the json loader would add random letters into the filename. Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce it at the moment as the code changed significantly over time.

Comment: Your files do not have the .h5 extension, while your loading code has it.

Comment: But they were save in h5, so they also have the extension... Right?
P.s. I will go to bed now and can further answer in the morning. Thanks so far

Comment: Look at your files, do they have the .h5 extension or not? Most likely not and that is the problem.

Comment: Cheers, I will check that tomorrow morning. Have a nice day.

Comment: Dear @Matias Valdenegro , thanks again for your input. The files were stored in h5 and therefore had the extension h5. The problem was that I forgot to give the full path for the h5 files as I did for the Json file. Stupid night-coding error. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working on Windows, so the case doesn't matter.

Demo:

```
In [39]: fn = 'd:/temp/AAAbbbCCCddd.txt'

In [40]: with open(fn, 'w') as f:
    ...:     f.write('Test')
    ...:
    ...:

In [41]: with open(fn.lower()) as f:
    ...:     #       ^^^^^^^^  <---- NOTE!  
    ...:     print(f.read())
    ...:
    ...:
Test
```

Try to specify a full path to your files

Comment: Dear MaXU, thanks a lot for your input. You where right, I forgot in the weight loading the destination. For the model I used `destination+modelname+'.json'` but for the h5stored weights only `modelweights+'.h5'` instead of `destination+modelweights+'.h5'` Thanks

Comment: @FloridaMan, glad i could help :)

Comment: funny how those small bugs keeps you busy the longest :-)